# java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE074 no Code attribute specified; class=javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet, method=<init>()V, pc=0?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-3

I am getting this error while starting the server?
'java.lang.ClassFormatError: JVMCFRE074 no Code attribute specified; class=javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet, method=()V, pc=0'

Can anybody help me to sort out this?

Comment: Which server are you using? Can you please describe in brief?

Comment: Websphere 8.5 and jdk 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try excluding javaee-api from dependencies:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <classpathDependencyExcludes>
        <classpathDependencyExclude>javax:javaee-api</classpathDependencyExclude>
      </classpathDependencyExcludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```